# RGB to XYZ and then XYZ to LAB in android(JAVA)

Tags: image-processing, rgb, android, opencv

I have calculated R,G and B values of an image and do some calculations to get L,a and b values for LAB Colorspace. Now how can I transfer my RGB image into LAB image using these L,a and b Values in Android studio (Except OpenCV's Builtin function because I want to first convert RGB into XYZ and then finally XYZ to LAB color space)?

Comment: why do you want to do RGB -> XYZ -> Lab?

Comment: I want to extract features of an image based on color difference.

Comment: and why not simply use RGB-> Lab? Which operation you do in XYZ which you cannot do in RGB?

Comment: I am following a research paper which describe so moreover I am strictly advised to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass **RGB** values to the function of this class which will return an array containing values of **LAB**

```
public class CIELab {
String TAG ="RGB";
public double[] rgbToLab(int R, int G, int B) {
    double[] lab=new double[3];
    double r, g, b, X, Y, Z, xr, yr, zr;
    ColorUtils.RGBToLAB(R,G,B,lab);
    //Core.absdiff();

    // D65/2°
    double Xr = 95.047;
    double Yr = 100.0;
    double Zr = 108.883;


    // --------- RGB to XYZ ---------//

    r = R/255.0;
    g = G/255.0;
    b = B/255.0;

    if (r > 0.04045)
        r = Math.pow((r+0.055)/1.055,2.4);
    else
        r = r/12.92;

    if (g > 0.04045)
        g = Math.pow((g+0.055)/1.055,2.4);
    else
        g = g/12.92;

    if (b > 0.04045)
        b = Math.pow((b+0.055)/1.055,2.4);
    else
        b = b/12.92 ;

    r*=100;
    g*=100;
    b*=100;
    Log.d(TAG,"R:"+r+" G:"+g+" B:"+b);
    X =  0.4124*r + 0.3576*g + 0.1805*b;
    Y =  0.2126*r + 0.7152*g + 0.0722*b;
    Z =  0.0193*r + 0.1192*g + 0.9505*b;


    // --------- XYZ to Lab --------- //

    xr = X/Xr;
    yr = Y/Yr;
    zr = Z/Zr;

    if ( xr > 0.008856 )
        xr =  (float) Math.pow(xr, 1/3.);
    else
        xr = (float) ((7.787 * xr) + 16 / 116.0);

    if ( yr > 0.008856 )
        yr =  (float) Math.pow(yr, 1/3.);
    else
        yr = (float) ((7.787 * yr) + 16 / 116.0);

    if ( zr > 0.008856 )
        zr =  (float) Math.pow(zr, 1/3.);
    else
        zr = (float) ((7.787 * zr) + 16 / 116.0);


    double[] lab = new double[3];

    lab[0] = (116*yr)-16;
    lab[1] = 500*(xr-yr);
    lab[2] = 200*(yr-zr);

    return lab;

   }
}
```